# Nestjs socket from exception filter context is defined even though exception comes from http request and there's no sockets within app?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-gateways, nestjs-exception-filters

I'm trying to use a "bad input exception filter" to catch errors and return them to the client. I have both websockets and http endpoints throughout my monorepo, on one application I have both.

The issue I'm having, I don't want to use two separate exception filters for WS & HTTP and until now I was relying on nestjs defining either the request or the socket context to tap into that and either return the error back to the websocket or returning the error via http res.send.

But it turns out they're both defined even when there's no websockets within the application at all, no adapter registered, nothing.

Exception handler:

```
    const req: IRequest = host.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const res: Response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    const socket: ISocket = host.switchToWs().getClient();
  

    if (req && res) {
     // returning req res
    }

    if (socket) {
      // emitting error on socket
```

Is there a way to either:

- prevent this
- tap into another value from the context to know where to return the error to

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something to take note of is that the `ExecutionContext` has an `args` property that is an array of values related to the request. The `switchTo*().get*()` methods are really just syntactic sugar for things like `getArgsByIndex()`. What you can do, instead of checking for truthiness of `req`, `res`, and `socket` is use the `getType()` property on the `ArgumentHost`/`ExecutionContext` which will return `http`, `ws`, `rpc`, or `graphql` depending on the request, and then you can separate out your error handling logic from there. I like to use a switch case for it, but if statements would work too

```js
switch (host.getType<ContextType | 'graphql'>()) {
  case 'http':
    return this.handleHttpError(exception, host);
  case 'graphql':
    return this.handleGqlError(exception, host);
  case 'ws':
    return this.handleWsError(exception, host);
  case 'rpc':
    return this.handleRpcError(exception, host);
}
```

I have something *similar* in an interceptor for logging, using `ExecutionContext` instead of `ArgumentHost`, but the idea should be the same. ExecutionContext just has a `getClass` and `getHandler` method